# Algorithm to Ascribe Value RStudio

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create an algorithm that essentially is a function of this data frame.

This is the code I was using, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I need image_id to be the independent variable so that when I input 7 into the function, I get back 10 and 15. If I were to input 8, I would get back 11 and 13.

`num = function(image_id, category_id, data = categories) {x->y}`

This is the data frame that I am using.

`category_id image_id cat_to_img_last_update
1           15       15                   NULL

2           11       11                   NULL
3           13       13                   NULL
4           10       10                   NULL
5           35       35                   NULL
6           78       78                   NULL
7          112      112                   NULL
8           61       61                   NULL
9           86       86                   NULL
10         101      101                   NULL
11          61       61                   NULL
12          86       86                   NULL`

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It is unclear what you are asking for in your question. Also it is always best to provide a minimal working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and for questions about R to use `dput()` to provide your data frame https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176460/how-to-paste-data-from-r-to-stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I hope my updated post is more palatable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need a function for this, but if you really want, here is what it would look like:

```
# Read in data
categories <- 
  data.frame(category_id = c(15,11,13,10,35,78,112,61,86,101,61,86),
             image_id = c(7,8,8,7,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

num <- function(image_id, data = categories) {
  data$category_id[data$image_id == image_id]
}

num(7) # 15 10
num(8) # 11 13
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. If I wanted to bypass concatenating the numbers, is there a way to do that simply with the variable names? Something similar to this?

categories <- 
  data.frame(category_id = c(catigories$image_id),
             image_id = c(catigories$category_id),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

num <- function(image_id, data = categories) {
  data$category_id[data$image_id == image_id]
}

num(7) # 15 10
num(8) # 11 13

Comment: categories_1 <- 
  data.frame(category_id = c(categories$category_id),
             image_id = c(categories$image_id),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

num <- function(image_id, data = categories) {
  data$category_id[data$image_id == image_id]
}

num(7) # 15 10
num(8) # 11 13


Just fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
    category_id = c(15, 11, 13, 10, 25, 78, 112, 61, 86, 101, 61, 86),
    image_id    = c(7, 8, 8, 7, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12)
)

myfun <- function(num) { sort(df[df$image_id == num, "category_id"]) }

myfun(7)
myfun(8)
```